# idempotent / non idempotent operations in java client server implementation

Tags: java, client-server

I have searched for examples on idempotent and non-idempotent operations but there aren't much on them that is relevant for implementation on a java client-server system. Can you guys give me some examples of both idempotent and non-idempotent operations that can be implemented for a java client-server system, primarily for text reading and insertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading operations should generally be idempotent by nature.  However, posting a text may not be.   With some systems, posting a text more than once results in both getting added separately.  If texts have permanent unique IDs (a new text can never reuse an older one's ID, even if the older one no longer exists), deletion by ID is also idempotent.

Comment: Thanks! but my client-server has already implemented reading, insertion and updates monitoring operations so I was just wondering if there are any other idempotent and non-idempotent operations that could be implemented?

Comment: @Laughy - there are an infinite number of idempotent and non-idempotent operations (in fact, _all_ operations fall into one of those 2 categories), so what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Hi, I am looking for any simple examples for non-idempotent and idempotent operations that can be implemented for a java client server that deals mainly with editing of text at the server through remote method invocation at the client side. Thanks!

Comment: Laughy, I've given you examples.  Like @jtahlborn, there an infinite number.  It depends what your app is really supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for your bank balance is idempotent. Transferring funds out of it isn't.